# Assigning WebSocket output to object in real time

Tags: r, websocket

The following code to produces a WebSocket which outputs received messages in the R console:

```
ws <- WebSocket$new(""ws://echo.websocket.org/"")
ws$onMessage(function(event) {
  cat(event$data)
})
```

I'm trying to find a way to assign the message received from the WebSocket server to an object in R (preferably as a character vector). I've tried to following:

```
ws$onMessage(function(event) {
  testobject<-cat(event$data)
})
```

and

```
ws$onMessage(function(event) {
  testobject<-capture.output(cat(event$data))
})
```

But neither of these approaches work. I'm aware that the `sink()` function can be used to transfer the console output to file format, but I'm hoping to use WebSocket data to update my R environment in real time. Is there any approach that will work for this case?